# Meaning of USB 2.0 high-speed/full-speed device/host/OTG controller ...?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, peripheral

In the datasheets of many MCUs, following are said about USB.

"USB 2.0 high-speed/full-speed device/host/OTG controller with dedicated DMA, on-chip full-speed PHY and ULPI"

I wonder what do the parts of the following term mean respectively?

"host/OTG controller with dedicated DMA, on-chip full-speed PHY and ULPI"

Thanks.

Comment: Which of those terms are unclear?

Comment: high speed is 480mbps, full is 12. host is the "computer" side, device is the "device" side, OTG is dual role. PHY is the component that generates the electric signal on the cable. ULPI is a standard interface between PHY and the rest of the USB controller.

Comment: ... all of which 5 minutes of wikipedia could have told KHK.

Comment: @Marus Muller: I am assuming you expect the OP to be a slow reader.

Comment: @PeterSmith :) point is that there's a lot of different things here, and we can't teach OP all about the basics of serial busses up to the specifics of the USB architecture. This is not a precise question as would fit on this site, this really reads a lot like "I noticed it'll be a lot of work to read all this, hopefully someone can read it for me and make the same amount of knowledge magically appear in my head", which, sadly, doesn't work.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, this was my first reaction too. But then it came to me that the OP lists several marketing catch-phrases, which need a bit of translation into engineering terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> device/host/OTG controller

means that the MCU has TWO controllers, one can serve as USB device (receive and decode USB traffic and do serial I/O data), and another controller that can serve as USB host, i.e. handling port connect/disconnect, generate frame traffic, and form sequences of USB packets in accord with control protocol. Both functions are usually multiplexed into one port, and therefore the entire design can have a role switch functionality (called "OTG").

> with dedicated DMA

means that the controllers utilize fast DMA mode for internal data transfer (and maybe having processed the entire USB token sequences), to offload MCU software from the routine job. Since it doesn't say if the controller conforms to any standard (like OHCI, UHCI, of EHCI), it means that it is proprietary, and needs custom software library to run.

> on-chip full-speed PHY

means that right out of the MCU IC there is only FS (12 Mbps) signal mode.

> and ULPI

means that to get HS (480 Mbps) speed, you need to attach an external PHY IC via ULPI interface, [something like THIS](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/USB3300), to get full range of USB speeds both for host and device modes. A single PHY chip will provide ALL modes.

Answer (score 0):

> USB 2.0 high-speed/full-speed device/host/OTG controller with dedicated DMA

This is a capability of the data handling part of the USB engine(s) on the chip.

> on-chip full-speed PHY and ULPI

From what is *not said*, this means that the chip is only self-sufficient for USB *full speed*.

To achieve USB high speed, you will need additional supporting chip(s).  Given that there are parts with everything needed for USB high speed internal, you may want to look elsewhere if you have a USB high speed requirement; but keep in mind you may need off chip buffer memory to fully utilize this anyway.

Comment: "on-chip full-speed PHY" does say that the MCU has full speed USB PHY on the chip. What else needs to be said to be more clear?

Comment: @AliChen the poster's other recent questions imply a USB high speed level of requirement specifically in the device role.  The key not-immediately-obvious thing that needs interpreting in the data sheet quote (in general, but especially for this poster) is the fact that the part *cannot* do high speed without additional helper parts - ie, there is no high speed PHY included.

Comment: ...and from that follows the most important part of the answer: this is not a good choice for the poster's needs, as too much supporting work will be needed to make it usable.